# Regex to search outside of specified tags

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to use regex to extract values which are not bound by certain tags (`<ins>` and `<del>`). For example:

```
<?php
$a = "this text <ins>is designed to</ins> give the impression of a real king <ins> cobra </ins> in desert";
preg_match_all("/(?<!<del>|<ins>)(.+)(?!<\/del>|<\/ins>)/", $a, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

I have tried this with lookarounds above, but no luck capturing what is outside of `ins` and `del` tags.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly should the output in this case be?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the text outside those tags, you can split the string using a regexp that matches the `<ins>.*?</ins>` or `<del>.*?</del>`, or even remove them completely. You will be left with the text which was around. I think using lookarounds can over-complicate the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp, it worked for me:

```
"/([^<>]+)|(?:<ins>[^<>]*<\/ins>)/"
```

Sorry had to fix it, those online regexp tools are not that reliable it seem :)
This is what I made it to work:

```
$string = 'this text <ins>is designed to</ins> give the impression of a real king <ins> cobra </ins> in desert';

preg_match_all('/([^<>]+)|(?:<ins>[^<>]*<\/ins>)/', $string, $match);

echo implode('', $match[1]);
```

Result:
this text  give the impression of a real king  in desert